# Rate of Convergence vs Radius of Convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, fibonacci-numbers

What is the difference between finding the 'rate of convergence' and the radius of convergence'? The question I am trying to solve here is to find the rate of convergence of the ratio of Fibonacci which is $\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}\to \phi$. Can someone guide me to how I would find the rate of convergence of this? And also tell me what the difference between radius and rate is?

Edit: I understand the difference, but I need help finding the rate of convergence of the ratio of Fibonacci which is $\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}\to\phi$

Comment: See [Radius of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence#Definition) and [rate of convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence#Basic_definition).

Comment: @RobertIsrael Oh. I get it now. But now how would I find the rate of convergence of this?

Answer (score 1):

If a sequence converges, then you can look at some different ideas. Radius of convergence has to do with **series**, and more specifically **the power series**.

However, radius of convergence asks "For what $x$ does the power series converge," but this is an interval, so why use the term radius? Well, this requires some proof, probably beyond the scope of this question, but the idea is that the interval is always symmetric about some $a \in \mathbb{R}$ for any power series of the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_{n}\cdot(x-a)^{n}$.

However, rate of convergence has to do with **sequences**, and is actually making rigorous the notion of "how quickly a sequence approaches its limit." This is accomplished by investigating: $lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|x_{n+1}-L|}{|x_{n}-L|}$ and by evaluating this limit, you can see if the sequence converges linearly, quadratically, etc.

As for your question, if you are actually looking at $$F_n=\frac{(1+\sqrt{5})^n-(1-\sqrt{5})^n}{2^n \cdot \sqrt{5}}$$

Can you solve the problem from here?

**Edit:**

$F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ where $n \geq 3$ and $F_0=0$ and  $F_{1}=1$.

But then consider the characteristic polynomial: $r^n=r^{n-1}+r^{n-2}$ which simplifies to $r^2=r+1$, meaning that $r^2-r-1=0$. Solve this, to obtain: $r_{1,2}=\frac{1 \pm \sqrt5}{2}$ .

But we want *all** of the possible roots, not just two of them, so we look at: $$F_n=A(\frac{1 + \sqrt 5}{2})^{k}+B(\frac{1 - \sqrt5}{2})^{k}$$

Now, can you use the constraints:

$F_0=0$ and  $F_{1}=1$ to finish?

**Edit 2:**
Rate of convergence is defined as: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|x_{n+1}-L|}{|x_{n}-L|}$. Substitute: $\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=x_n$, and then evaluate the limit. If You

Comment: Where does this come from?

Comment: will edit, sorry.

Comment: I still don't see how this would give me the rate of convergence.

Comment: I see, well this translates a recursion into a language we know how to handle. It gives you a genuine expression for $F_n$ that only depends on its starting numbers. From this, you can get a closed form for $F_{n+1}/F_n$. Then you can use the limit definition I provided for rate of convergence to solve. After you get a closed form, it's not too bad.

Comment: Can you tell me this, that what does it mean to find the rate of convergence for this? Can you restate the question for me?

Comment: edited again. I'm not sure I can provide enough intuition for recursive sequences, characteristic polynomials, substitutions, rates of convergence, and limit definitions, all in one answer.

Comment: Is this what you're trying to show? https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Binet%27s_Formula

Comment: Yes, although I'm using a more general method made rigorous by something known as the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial)

Comment: Wait so the answer is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$?

Comment: the rate of convergence? I'm not sure, I did not actually compute it

Comment: I know, but according to the website, is that approach correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take for example the [geometric sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression),

$$a_n=a_0q^n$$

The Rate of convergence is
$q$

And the Radius of convergence is the values of $q$ for which:
$$a_0\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{q^i}<\infty$$
The radius in this case is
$$-1<q<1$$

Comment: Can you help me with my edit?